# Flutter: How to reopen pages, if they are already pushed on the stack?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm learning Flutter and I have a question about navigation. My app has 3 pages each containing the same drawer, which is navigating between them with navigator.push(). Now I can push the "same" page over and over again and then with the back button (navigator.pop) reopen them one after another. Is there a way to create every page only once and then reopen it, if it's already pushed to the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a way to do it, but without Navigator. I've put all Scaffolds inside PageWiew, disabled swipe action and added AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to every page. In the drawer, I changed Navigator.push code with PageController.jumpToPage. now it is working as I wanted, but I'm still wondering if this is the "right" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can create once and then reopen it(saving the state and everything), but I think this methods will help you to achieve what you want.

[popUntil](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html)

[pushAndRemoveUntil](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

And there many static methods in the [Navigator class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) documentation that might be useful.

Comment: The only way that I can think of to solve the problem with Navigator class is by having a list of open pages. Then in the drawer I need to check, if the page I want to open is already on the stack and if so use popUntil else push it on the stack. Then I need to update list of pages. the problem here is, that I would lose a page (e.g. pages 1,2, and 3: In list are 1 and 2 and i want to open 1 again -> i popUntil 1 and lost page 2...). Also I'm not sure how efficient this would be.